# Safari Web Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, css, debug, safari

Where do you enable web developer tools in Safari on windows? I can't find it anywhere. A quick web search found some really complicated instructions that felt more like a hack then turning on a setting. Does Apple really make it that hard to develop in their browser?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For quick access using a mouse, be sure to go into **Preferences**, **Advanced**, and check the **'Show Develop menu in menu bar'**.  Then, select 'show menu bar' from the gear menu (if you haven't already).

The 'Develop' menu now appears and has lots of options for you!

Comment: This is the real answer. I'd forgotten that you had to enable it.

Comment: Yep.  They can be tricky, those Apple devs.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, or right-click anywhere on a page and click "Inspect Element".

Comment: Note that "Inspect element" only shows up if the "Develop" menu is enabled.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut only works under that condition also (but upvoted because I didn't know it)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> on Mac, or you can right-click anywhere on a page and click "Inspect Element" after having set preferences given in correct answer.